# Partial ordering and equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, math-history

How did our earlier scientists come to know that a relation is a partial order iff it reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive (RAT), and that a relation is an equivalence relation iff it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive (RST)? I want to know the reasoning behind the selection of properties behind these two definitions.

Comment: As for many concepts in mathematics, notion of relations (both equivalence and partial ordered) must have evolve with time and probably many people had a vague idea of this concept at the same time.

Comment: [See this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135347/who-introduced-the-terms-equivalence-relation-and-equivalence-class) for some references.

Comment: Who will discuss process of evolution for partial ordering and equivalence relation?